# How to identify from Tika extracted text data from outlook msg file if there was an attachment

Tags: outlook, apache-tika

I've raw text data which has been extracted from outlook msg (1 email) using Apache Tika.
It appears that binary data in the email, e.g., images or other binary attachments were converted to Base64 in the final text form of entire email.

Which fields or block should I look for in this raw text to identify if there was an attachment at all? If it was present how do I extract those properly and save those separately?

OK, looks like the email header field is `X-MS-Has-Attach` to indicate if there is/are attachment(s). But which field would contain the attachment data?

Comment: Are you using the recursive metadata wrapper, or your own custom class to handled attachments/embedded resources?

Comment: I'm using custom class. However, it'd helpful if you could answer with recursive metadata wrapper.